# iFrame Resizer setting incorrect height before images have loaded

Tags: iframe-resizer

I'm using @DavidJBradshaw's iFrame Resizer and have run into a problem that I can't seem to find an answer for.

iFrame Resizer appears to be setting the iframe height before images have loaded, and when the images finally load the iframe is too short. Any click or window resize immediately triggers iFrame Resizer to set the correct height.

The issue appears to be only when a new page (from the same domain) is loaded into the iFrame for the first time. Everything works fine when testing my site locally, it also works fine when the browser has cached all the files, so returning to a page that didn't size correctly on the first view works fine.

Here are the iframe tags:

```html
<iframe id="newsframe" src="foo.html" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here's what I have at the end of the page containing the iframe:

```html
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
        $("#graphic").hide().css("visibility", "visible").fadeIn(200);
      });
    
      iFrameResize({ log: false }, '#newsframe')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's what I have at the end of the iframe html:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```